# Pointer to boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I have a problem about the managed of thread.

My problem is that I want to create a class ThreadManager that have to manage all thread created and of course also destroy this thread.

```
class DerivedInterface
{
public:
    DerivedInterface():id("Test"){};
    virtual ~DerivedInterface(){};
    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual std::string getId() = 0;
    const std::string  id ;
};

class Object : public DerivedInterface
{
public:
    Object():id("VirtualDae"){};
    ~Object(){}

    void run()
    {

        std::cout<<"i'M IN RUN"<<std::endl;

        bool flag = true;

        while(flag){
            //allocate x resources

            try{
                //do some process on resources
                boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
                //clean resources
            }
            catch(boost::thread_interrupted const& )
            {
                //clean resources
                std::cout << "Worker thread interrupted" << std::endl;
                flag = false;
            }
            catch(std::exception x){
                std::cout<<"exx"<<x.what()<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    std::string getId(){
        return id;
    }

    const std::string  id ;
};
class ThreadManager
{
public:

void createThread(DerivedInterface& t)
{
    boost::thread t1(&DerivedInterface::run, &t); 
    insert(&t1);

}

     }
/*
 * This method insert the pointer of the thread in a
 * map
 */

void insert(boost::thread* t1)
{

    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);

    int size = threadsMap.size()+1;

    std::cout<<"Size :"<<size<<std::endl;

    threadsMap.insert(std::make_pair(size, t1));
}

/*
 * This method return the pointer of the thread
 * inserted in a map
 */

boost::thread*  get(int key){

    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);

    if(threadsMap.find(key)!=threadsMap.end()){
        std::cout<<"non null get"<<std::endl;

        return threadsMap[key];
    }else{
        std::cout<<" null get"<<std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}


/*
 * This method stop the thread corrisponding
 * to the position pos as parameter in the map
 */
void stop(int pos){
    std::cout<<"Stop"<<std::endl;

    boost::thread* thread = get(pos);

    std::cout<<"thread  null"<<std::endl;

    if(thread != NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"thread not null"<<std::endl;
        thread->interrupt();

        std::cout << "Worker thread finished" << std::endl;
    }
}

     private:

boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> _mThread;

typedef std::map<int, boost::thread*> ThreadMapT;

ThreadMapT threadsMap;

std::map<int,boost::thread*>::iterator it;

boost::mutex m_mutex;

boost::thread_group g;

     };


   int main(){

    ThreadManager manager;
Object v;
//
manager.createThread(v);

std::cout<<"Interrupt"<<std::endl;

boost::thread *t1= manager.get(1);

t1->interrupt();
//
boost::posix_time::time_duration timeout = boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10000);
if (manager.get(1)->timed_join(timeout))
{
    //finished
    std::cout << "Worker thread finished" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    //Not finished;
    std::cout << "Worker thread not finished" << std::endl;
}

     }
```

the function t1.interrupt or manager.stop return segmantation fault ..

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f3e1d095993 in boost::thread::get_thread_info() const () from libboost_thread.so.1.51.0
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007f3e1d095993 in boost::thread::get_thread_info() const () from libboost_thread.so.1.51.0
#1  0x00007f3e1d0965c6 in boost::thread::interrupt() () from libboost_thread.so.1.51.0
#2  0x00000000004088a9 in main ()
```

Pointer of boost::thread is not null, so what happen? Thank you in advance.

Whey I can't do something like this ?

```
boost::thread *t1 = new boost::thread(&DerivedInterface::run, &t);
```

Comment: I tried this once, and [found it very difficult](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/have-i-thought-of-everything-in-this-wrapper-around-boostthread-group).

Comment: BTW your indentation is all messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void createThread(DerivedInterface& t)
{
    boost::thread t1(&DerivedInterface::run, &t); 
    insert(&t1);
}
```

In the above `t1` object gets created on the stack, then a pointer to `t1` gets inserted into the map and then `t1` goes out of scope and gets destroyed, so that all existing pointers to it become invalid.

You can fix it by passing around `shared_ptr<thread>` instead of `thread*`:

```
void insert(boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>);
void createThread(DerivedInterface& t)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> t1(new boost::thread(&DerivedInterface::run, &t)); 
    insert(t1);
}
```

Or, by using r-value references in C++11:

```
void insert(boost::thread&& t1);

void createThread(DerivedInterface& t)
{
    boost::thread t1(&DerivedInterface::run, &t); 
    insert(std::move(t1));
}
```

Alternatively, use [`boost::thread_group`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup) that does the above for you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would it also work to make t1 a `boost::thread* t1 = new boost::thread(...);` then delete all of them in the de-constructor?

Comment: mmm my object DerviedObject is extended by other object, so when I create a new object I want to matain a collection of these object (thread) instanciated, and of course delete all. If I use a group of thread , how can I interrupt one of them?? However the follow instruction doesn't work on my environmente:

boost::thread* t1 = new boost::thread(...)

however you are right , probably I should use a shared_ptr<thread>

Comment: If I use a group of thread , the logic of createThread is always not correct because is out of scope and then failed, but the second way doens't work (insert(std::move(t1));)

Comment: @Prisco I wouldn't use thread interruptions at all because it's non-trivial to make sure terminated threads clean up resources correctly and not leave anything in an inconsistent state. Especially if you use 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin could you help me to use shared_ptr<thread> ?

something like this?

 void createThread(DerivedInterface& t)
 {
  boost::thread t1(&DerivedInterface::run, &t);

  boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> shar = t1;

  insert(&shar);
 }

Comment: @Prisco added an example to the answer for you.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin the result is the same... probably there is something I wrong? have you tested your suggestion? (just for curiosity) thank you however!

Comment: I have solved this problem changed the structure of this class , probably in this case was more simple.. thank you all