# How to safely delete a thread pointer in a destructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Say, I have a C++ class including a thread pointer as a member variable. The thread keeps running until the program exits. **If I delete the pointer in the destructor, it seems that the thread has not yet finished at that moment?** What is the best practice to manage this or any tricks?

Sample code:

```
class Car {
public:
    Car();
    ~Car();
private:
    boost::thread *m_runningThreadPtr;
};


Car::Car() {
    m_runningThreadPtr = new boost::thread();
}

Car::~Car() {
    delete m_runningThreadPtr;    // The thread should be still running now. 
                                  // Problematic if it was deleted here?
}
```

Comment: Try to handle with boost::shared_ptr 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823300/pointer-to-boostthread
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html

Comment: Why are you using `new` for the thread in the first place? It seems quite unnecessary.

Comment: you should exit that thread gracefully, then join to wait it to end, like this: Car::~Car() {m_runningThreadPtr->join();
    delete m_runningThreadPtr; }

Answer (score 1):

By default the destructor will call `terminate()` to kill the thread if it's still running, whether this is safe or not depends on what the thread is doing at the time. You can call `join()` before deleting it if you want to wait for the thread to finish, and use some sort of synchronization system (even just a global flag) that tells the thread to quit.

Comment: Note that this is `boost::thread`, not `std::thread`. It will call `detach`, not `terminate`. Insofar, deleting the thread object is "harmless" (though still not advisable) as the detached thread will not be killed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of behavior you're looking for.

If you want to delete the object, and have it stop its owned thread and then delete its thread object, then you should have a stop flag which your thread checks from time to time. In the destructor, you'd set the stop flag, and then call `join()` on your thread. Once it returns, you can safely delete the pointer.

If, on the other hand, you want to delete the object and have the thread go on its own until it finishes, then you need a more clever mechanism, like at the end of your thread function, posting to the main thread of your application a callback that calls `join()` on your thread and then `delete`s it. For that, of course, you'll need to have in your thread function a pointer to your thread object.

**EDIT**
In the case of `boost::thread`, it simply detaches in its destructor, so for the second option you can safely delete it when you're done.
It's important to note, however, that this won't work with `std::thread`'s destructor, which will terminate your program in such a case. But then you can also manually call `detach()` and then `delete`. So you really have to look at the API you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete it. Have the thread delete itself when done.

Comment: This might be dangerous depending on the API. E.g. the thread object's destructor might call `join()` on itself, effectively causing a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is done when there's no more code to run. Are your threads still running code? Then why do you think your program is done?

So, it's reasonable to assume your threads are i fact done. That means you can call `.join()` on the thread, after which it is OK to call `delete`.