# C++ Boost Thread ID Access

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a question on thread ID access. On a system level, I have multiple threads running in parallel at the same time. At any given time, I would like the parent thread/main thread to be able to interrupt a specific spawned thread via thread ID. Reading on up the thread management documentation from Boost, I see that I can do something like this:

```
//global 
boost::thread::id threadID = boost::thread::id(); //at this point, it's defined as a not-any-thread

void thread_to_interrupt()
{
    threadID = boost::this_thread::get_id(); //grabs current thread ID and stores it in global
}

void main()
{
    //some code here will set condition_for_new_thread to TRUE
    if(condition_for_new_thread == 1)
    {
        boost::thread newThread(&thread_to_interrupt);
    }
    ... //other process stuff
    //NOTE: at this point I want to interrupt thread_to_interrupt() based on thread ID
    if(condition_to_interrupt_thread == 1)
    {
        newThread.interrupt(); //won't compile here because newThread was created inside an if-condition
        //Maybe try to interrupt based on threadID somehow? Not sure how to implement it
    }
}
```

So basically, how do I interrupt based on thread ID? Is there a generic function that I can use? Or, can I initialize a new thread but not point it to any subroutine, so that newThread.interrupt() will compile.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What about declaring the thread outside the if block and assigning to the thread function?

Comment: That's one of the options that can work, but how do I declare a thread but not attach it to a particular subroutine? Not super proficient in boost, and the documentation has a lot of info to digest...

Comment: `boost::thread t;` creates a thread that isn't attached to a subroutine. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: how do I then attach it to a subroutine later on? I tried just newThread(&thread_to_interrupt) but that doesn't work. If I do boost::thread newThread(&thread_to_interrupt) then would it just redefine the first declaration or would it actually have declared 2 different threads?

Comment: `t = boost::thread(&thread_to_interrupt)`.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know all the thread operators that I can use, but that works, thank you! To bug you one last time (and for my knowledge), is there a way to interrupt or operate on a thread based on thread ID?

Comment: `this_thread::get_id()` returns the ID of the currently executing thread, this value can be checked within the thread function so you know which thread to operate on. You can also store your threads in some data structure like a set or map. In C++11 the threads will be stored based on their IDs.

Comment: Thanks again! Yeah, I can grab the thread ID, how do I operate based on that from a different thread? I want to have some way of operating on it, such as boost::<threadID>.interrupt()...

Comment: You'd have to access the thread through a data structure, so when you have the ID, use that value to get the thread instance and then call `interrupt()` on it. Put your threads into a data structure that can be accessed by the thread functions.

Comment: @stackedcards88, please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823300/pointer-to-boostthread, Checkout ThreadManager class implementation.